# My Private key from myetherwallet.com was stolen, Can I add more steps to access my wallet?

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp

yesterday I was cheated by this MEW address user:0x83ecb676706aa5c7cf72384723935dd1195dcb3e He/She sent my 0.2549 Eth from my ETH Wallet address :0xe6b0d7f7d18c14015d47ecc77cf5c0009f34bb18 Shit!!!
when the scammer know my private key by cheating to make something like https://www.myetherwallet.com/ front page.Can we add more steps than using only private key to make the scammer can not access my wallet again and again

Answer (score 1):

No way, you'd better to use new wallet and should use MEW with metamask or with cold storage for more secure.

Answer (score 1):

MyEtherWallet has notorious click-click-click process telling you what you should do whenever you enter their homepage. It gives you a lot of good tips and hints on how to secure your account. Furthermore, when starting to enter your private key on their website it specifically tells you "this is a bad idea".

As you are probably aware of currently, you should always be very careful with your private key and double-check everything. And yes, for example Metamask is a good addition to security.